# Dataframe. Split string from X to column value

Tags: dataframe, split

I have a dataframe like this one: (comes from the Chess Game Dataset)

| moves | number_of_opening_moves |
| --- | --- |
| e4 e5 Nf3 d6 d4 Nc6 d5 Nb4 a3 Na6 Nc3 Be7 b4 | 5 |
| e4 e5 Bc4 Nc6 Nf3 Nd4 d3 Nxf3+ Qxf3 | 4 |
| e4 e6 d4 d5 e5 c5 c3 Nc6 Nf3 Qb6 Be3 Qxb2 | 2 |
| e4 e5 Nf3 Nc6 Bc4 Nf6 Nc3 Bc5 O-O O-O d3 Ne8 | 5 |

I want to split the moves column (creating a new one for example) by the number of opening_moves indicated in the following column.
Desired result:

| moves | number_of_opening_moves | opening_moves |
| --- | --- | --- |
| e4 e5 Nf3 d6 d4 Nc6 d5 Nb4 a3 Na6 Nc3 Be7 b4 | 5 | e4 e5 Nf3 d6 d4 |
| e4 e5 Bc4 Nc6 Nf3 Nd4 d3 Nxf3+ Qxf3 | 4 | e4 e5 Bc4 Nc6 |
| e4 e6 d4 d5 e5 c5 c3 Nc6 Nf3 Qb6 Be3 Qxb2 | 2 | e4 e6 |
| e4 e5 Nf3 Nc6 Bc4 Nf6 Nc3 Bc5 O-O O-O d3 Ne8 | 3 | e4 e5 Nf3 |

It sounds simple, but I didn't manage to find a similar post.
This doesn't work:

```
split()[0:'number_of_opening_moves':3]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try list comprehension:

```
df['opening_moves'] = [x.split()[:int(i)] for x, i in zip(df['moves'], df['number_of_opening_moves'])]
```

Comment: To convert from list to string you can use this afterwards "df['opening_moves'] = [' '.join(str(i) for i in x) for x in df['opening_moves']]"